# Can I create a Excel workbook inside a foreach in perl?

Tags: excel, perl

I want to create multiple Excel files. The files will output basically the same format, the only difference the data will be for different years.

If I run the program in the following way it runs and create the excel file without problems:

```
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Date::Parse;

... ###some validation of the data to work with
... ### put data on hashes
...

 my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "Monitoring_Report_2013.xlsx" );
 $worksheet1  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q1');
 $worksheet2  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q2');
 $worksheet3  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q3');
 $worksheet4  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q4');

... ### create the different tables on each worksheet
...
...
```

If I add the foreach part so it can creates automatically the differents files to each year it runs but when I tried to open the excel file it generate a corrupt error.

```
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Date::Parse;

...
...
...


my @years_in_data = ("2012", "2013", "2014");


foreach my $year(@years_in_data)
{
    chomp $year;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( "Monitoring_Report_$year.xlsx" );
    $worksheet1  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q1');
    $worksheet2  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q2');
    $worksheet3  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q3');
    $worksheet4  = $workbook->add_worksheet('Q4');

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Can I create the files automatically or I need to write each file manually??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I remove the foreach part and just do one year, the Excel file is generated without problems.

Comment: I can't replicate. You left out the actual cause of the problem. Please provide code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Note: You should always use `use strict;`.

Comment: The code works correctly. Also, you don't need `$worksheet1`,... `$worksheet4` variables.

Comment: are you averse to outputting csv or xls?

Comment: It generates a .xlsx file

Comment: When you run this exact sample of code, do you have issues?  
No one else is able to recreate the problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry, the program is about 600 lines. I just wrote the part that was giving me problems. Let me see if I can put most of the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the $worksheet->write() method for each of these ? Maybe you are saying you do with all the dots. If you don't then I can see none of them getting written.

Comment: I used   $worksheet1->write_row( $row_counter+12, $column_counter, \@headers, $format_wrap );
  
  #Write the total row
  
  $worksheet1->write_col( $row2, $column_counter, $data_total_for_table, $format_total );                                                  for each worksheet